# Curve Building + Swap Pricing

Tags: interest-rates, yield-curve, interest-rate-swap

Assume Swap means a USD Swap with standard conventions (semi-annual fixed payments and quarterly floating payments, etc).

Comment: why are your USD swap rates 100%/200% ?

Comment: arbitrarily picked, just wanted high rates and steep to highlight any issues in methodology.

Comment: You cannot interpolate linearly your rates. I'm curious about the contraints you're using for your solver but I think you're mixing up the swap curve and the libor3m forward curve.
Just having the 1Y/2Y swap rate is insufficient information to build a forward curve. You can only compute the 1Y forward swap in 1 Y with that set of info.